# Showing multiple nested items from JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse some data from a JSON file in PHP. Now, I had it working locally, but then when I put it live on the website, I got warning errors ( Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() )

Please help, I'm new to this and going around in circles reading things and trying to figure it out.

Basically, I want to list all the "artists" and include their name, UUID and image.

The JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": null,
            "itemType": "artist",
            "moreTrackingTitle": "All Artists",
            "items": [
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist One",
                    "UUID": "364226",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com",
                },
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist Two",
                    "UUID": "1513513",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com",
                },
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist Three",
                    "UUID": "214141",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com",
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    "nextPageToken": null
}
```

The PHP

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'http://EXTERNAL-JSON-FILE' );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

    $data =json_decode($body, true);

    foreach($data as $k1 => $v1) {
        foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
            foreach($v2 as $k3 => $v3) {
                foreach($v3 as $artist) {
                    echo $artist['Artist'];
                    echo $artist['UUID'];
                    echo $artist['Image'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Invalid JSON

`json_decode` fails (silently) and returns `null` because this is not a valid JSON document. JSON does not allow a comma on the last item of an array or the last listed property of an object. Where did you get this JSON document from? This is valid Javascript, but not valid JSON.

The offending lines are:

```
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist One",
                    "UUID": "364226",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com", <-- remove this in the other objects too
                },
```

and

```
                }
            ]
        }, <-- remove this
    ],
    "nextPageToken": null
}
```

Hopefully you own this "external json file" and can edit it, otherwise there's no way around it. Check your json files with a [json linter](https://jsonlint.com/).

## Wrong use of nested `foreach` loops

To get what you want (assuming each item is a "artist"):

```php
foreach($data["items"] as $item){
    foreach($item["items"] as $artist){
        echo $artist["Artist"];
        echo $artist["UUID"];
        echo $artist["Image"];
    }
}
```

You should not `foreach` every property of JSON objects, only the ones that are iterable.

### Appendix

Here is the fixed json file, with the offending commas removed:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": null,
            "itemType": "artist",
            "moreTrackingTitle": "All Artists",
            "items": [
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist One",
                    "UUID": "364226",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com"
                },
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist Two",
                    "UUID": "1513513",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com"
                },
                {
                    "Artist": "Artist Three",
                    "UUID": "214141",
                    "Image": "http://theurl.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "nextPageToken": null
}
```

To force PHP to throw an exception when it reads invalid JSON strings instead of returning null, pass JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR as the fourth parameter:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Comment: This is great feedback. Thank you for taking the time to help.